# Parse string and NSLog array

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nslog

Good day!

I tryed to parse string with such format:

```
 {"code":200,"serviceID":"53d22b10e46a5","sender":1,"hasPair":0}
```

Code:

```
 NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSRange   searchedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [strData length]);
NSLog(@"Data from server = %@", strData);
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\w+)?([0-9])" options:0 error:&error];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:strData options:0 range: searchedRange];
NSLog(@"The content of arry is%@", matches);
```

And the last `NSLog` show me the next

```
The content of arry is(
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x71a9e90>{8, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x71a4370> (w+)?([0-9]) 0x0}",
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x71a9d70>{9, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x71a4370> (w+)?([0-9]) 0x0}",
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x71a9d90>{10, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x71a4370> (w+)?([0-9]) 0x0}",
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x71a9c80>{25, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x71a4370> (w+)?([0-9]) 0x0}",
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x71a9ca0>{26, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x71a4370> (w+)?([0-9]) 0x0}",
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x71a3460>{28, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x71a4370> (w+)?([0-9]) 0x0}",
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x71aa380>{29, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x71a4370> (w+)?([0-9]) 0x0}",
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x71aa3a0>{31, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x71a4370> (w+)?([0-9]) 0x0}",
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x71a9770>{32, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x71a4370> (w+)?([0-9]) 0x0}",
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x71a3440>{34, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x71a4370> (w+)?([0-9]) 0x0}",
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x71a9790>{35, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x71a4370> (w+)?([0-9]) 0x0}",
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x71aa320>{37, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x71a4370> (w+)?([0-9]) 0x0}",
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x71aa340>{49, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x71a4370> (w+)?([0-9]) 0x0}",
    "<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x71a8f30>{61, 1}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x71a4370> (w+)?([0-9]) 0x0}"
)
```

But I want to parse info from server and save it into array. Please, tell me my mistakes.
Thank you!

Comment: Looks like JSON.  Is it?

Comment: I study Objective-C only for a month) May be you're right... Sorry((

Answer (score 1):

Your input string looks like JSON, therefore using [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html) will work better than using a regular expression:

```
NSString *json = @"{\"code\":200,\"serviceID\":\"53d22b10e46a5\",\"sender\":1,\"hasPair\":0}";
NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;
id obj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                         options:0
                                           error:&error];
if (obj) {
    NSAssert([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]], @"Expected a dictionary");
    NSDictonary *dictObj = (NSDictionary *)obj;
    NSNumber *code = dictObj[@"code"];
    NSString *serviceId = dictObj[@"serviceID"];
    NSNumber *sender = dictObj[@"sender"];
    NSNumber *hasPair = dictObj[@"hasPair"];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Failed to parse JSON: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Is it works when all params (code, serviceId, sender and hasPair) different then now? I get this info from server

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work  
  -[__NSCFConstantString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x47a8
2014-07-25 13:31:53.667 Nanny[1130:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x47a8'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c91012 0x10cee7e 0x1d1c4bd 0x1c80bbc 0x1c8094e 0xc0282e 0xc029dd 0xc02fa5 0x2b18 0x279b 0xf41c7 0xf4232 0x433d5 0x4376f 0x43905 0x4c917 0x1096c 0x1194b 0x22cb5 0x23beb 0x15698 0x1becdf9 0x1becad0 0x1c06bf5 0x1c06962 0x1c37bb6 0x1c36f44 0x1c36e1b

Comment: @vikichocolate Ah yes; that method wants an `NSData` object.  I will update the answer.  However if you are getting an `NSData` object from the server you won't need to convert it to a string first though, OK?

Comment: No, I must use regular expressions. I can't use JSON in this task.

Comment: @vikichocolate I understood that JSON was what you were getting from the server.  JSON is a string format for representing structured data,  like a simplified XML.

Comment: NO!!!!! This method parse only for this string   @"{\"code\":200,\"serviceID\":\"53d22b10e46a5\",\"sender\":1,\"hasPair\":0}";
But all params not constants, this string can be different

Comment: F.e. {"code":206,"serviceID":"53d23553e625d","sender":0,"hasPair":1}

Comment: @vikichocolate It will parse whatever input string you give it.  The hardcoded string in my answer is just an example and I expected you to pass it whatever data was received from the server.